# How do I set up an Intel SGX project targeting a Linux machine on Windows using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-studio, sgx

I'm running Windows. I would like to get project templates/Visual Studio/MSBuild integration for Intel SGX SDK when I'm targeting a remote Linux machine. All the tutorials and Intel documentation only refer to a Windows target with a Windows development machine.
I have already installed the SGX SDK on the remote Linux machine.

Comment: I would suggest installing linux as guest OS and focusing on coding instead of Windows/Linux crossdeveloping problems

Comment: @0___________ On Linux, the problem is with setting up Makefiles, etc. The Intel SGX SDK's sample makefiles are hundreds of lines long, and I need a simpler interface to get the job done. I don't have the time to focus on debugging Makefile problems. There's no official CMake solution available either, though I've managed to find an unofficial repo containing some helper functions. That's why I want to use the official development tools and have less of a headache.